How to set up AWS GuardDuty via invitation method in Terraform?
Is it only possible to use Terraform with AWS Organizations? All of the examples I have come across seem to be AWS Organization method instead of the now-legacy invitation method. How can this be done? Any github examples?
I've gone through the documentation in AWS, terraform just essentially describes the individual resources, but not so much how they work together. Any help is much appreciated!

Have you tried viewing the documentation for older versions of the provider?

What you are asking for is probably the aws_service_access_principals argument in the aws_organizations_organzation resource.

No, this is definitely not what I want, because like I said: in the console, there are 2 methods of doing this (invitation method, which is legacy, and the current organizations method). I do NOT want to use AWS Organizations to set up GuardDuty in terraform. I need multiaccount invitation method terraform GuardDuty setup. @MarkoE
